# How to enable hotspot button on Samsung S23?

Tags: samsung, tethering

I recently switched to a Samsung S23, Android version 13.

It seems that in the quick setting buttons (when you swipe down), the button "Hotspot" is missing, which toggles whether the phone provides a wi-fi hotspot for other devices.

There are some online articles discussing that this setting might be disabled based on your provider. I have bought the phone independently from a provider.

I tried [this workaround described by XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-restore-mobile-data-quick-settings-tile-toggle-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/) which uses *adb* to add *MobileData* and *Hotspot* to the *sysui_qs_tiles* list. However, that does not seem to have an effect, the desired button does not show up.

Any suggestions of what I might try?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the provider controls this, I  assume via the Sim. if your plan does not offer hotspots, then you cant enable it.